# Is it possible to have a ferrocenol?

Tags: organometallic-compounds

I'm specifically talking about having a hydroxy- group on the ferrocene ring.

Is it simply impossible because the ring is anionic?
I haven't seen any hydroxyferrocene molecules available online. (unless they are a [methanol group](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/335061?lang=en&region=CA))

Comment: Ring isn't really anionic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we can have hydroxyferrocene.  See [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=iovsCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA265&lpg=PA265&dq=hydroxy+ferrocene&source=bl&ots=pzM1NIoLD1&sig=zz6Brf6CQ9wiysOf_zZ0yXDwbLY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR1LTggK3eAhUj7oMKHahiD5E4ChDoATABegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=hydroxy%20ferrocene&f=false) for a brief summary description of possible synthesis and a nucleophile substitution reaction forming alkoxyferrocenes.